# Why am I getting an 'Invalid Number' error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So, i created two triggers on this one table. (LOAD). The LOAD table has the following columns:

```
row_id varchar(4000) --> created by a trigger everytime a row is inserted into the 'LOAD' table
UTCOffset Number
Data_Date Varchar2(7)
Data_Type Varchar2(4)
PostedValue Varchar2(4000)
UTCValue Timestamp(6)
Hour Number 
Data_Code Varchar2(5)
```

I am trying to insert data into the (VALUE) table that has the following columns:

```
Value_id --> created by a trigger everytime a row is inserted into the 'LOAD' table
Product_Id NUMBER
Source_Id Number
Unit_Cd Varchar2(50)
VALUE_TX VARCHAR2(4000)
UTC_Offset (Number)
Data_date (VARCHAR2(7))
HR_UTC VARCHAR2(4)
HR Timestamp(6)
HR_num Number
Data_Code Varchar2(5)
Create_Dt (autogenerated?)
Create_User_id (autogenerated)
Modify_dt (always null)
Modify_user_id (always null)
effective_dt (always null)
inactive_dt (always null)
```

I created the following triggers:
 1) **trigger to auto populate row_id for the LOAD table:**

```
create or replace trigger xml_load_trigger
before insert on load
for each row
begin
  :new.row_id := row_id_increase.nextval;
END;
/
```

2) ***trigger to insert data from LOAD table to VALUE table.** **NOTE: **Some of these values are hardcoded for testing purposes only.

```
create or replace trigger xml_load_trigger_value_930
AFTER INSERT
on load
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO VALUE
(value_id, product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_Date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_Dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
values('3', 'Mwh', null, null, :NEW.PostedValue, :NEW.UTCOffset, :NEW.Data_Date, :NEW.Data_Type, :NEW.UTCValue, :NEW.Hour, :NEW.data_code, null, null, null, null, null, null);
end;
/
```

Both of the triggers compile; however, when i try to load the some data into the 'LOAD' (staging) table, i get the following error: **SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number**

These are the values that I am trying to insert into the 'LOAD' (staging) table

```
insert into load (utcOffset, data_date, data_type, postedvalue, utcvalue, hour, data_code)
values(3, '1082019', 'UTC0', '2019-04-19 5:00', '19-APR-19 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 2, 'SYS');
```

Why am i getting this error? I've tried switching out my insert values to make sure they conform to the set standards of my tables but i can't seem to pintpoint what is going on... Or is this the wrong approach and/or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Storing a number in a string is not the right approach.

Comment: which column are you referring to? unfortunately the columns in my LOAD (staging) table reflect the same datatypes that are present in the existing VALUE table in the database so I had to make the datatypes in my LOAD(staging) table the same as what is in the Value table.

Comment: I'm somewhat baffled by your code. For example, your trigger `INSERT` inserts into the `value_id` column of the `value` table, but your description of the `value` table doesn't have a `value_id`. Could you produce a small verifiable example that actually runs and produces the error, with the real `CREATE TABLE`... etc code? (Bonus: you may find that trying to produce a small working example shows you what the problem actually is.)

Comment: (Also, as an aside, calling a column `row_id` in an RDBMS that has a commonly-used builtin [pseudocolumn called `rowid`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) is probably just asking for confusion...)

Comment: some of column's data type's are not clear. For example : column `Data_Type`'s ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - sorry i must've forgot to add them in my description. I've added them now, they are consistent with the datatypes present in the other table.

Comment: @MattGibson Typo, my apologies. I referred to value_Id as row_Id in my original post. I've edited it so that the column reads 'value_id' now... What I have on there is literally a copy and paste of what I have tried. The value table is a table already present in the database. I've created the LOAD (staging) table, and the 2 triggers (both compiiled). The error is when I try to load data into the LOAD (staging) table.

Comment: You're still missing other columns you refer to in the trigger (e.g. `inactive_dt`). Why not show us the actual table definitions? You're just making this harder than it needs to be - [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is useful for us and often for you.

Comment: @AlexPoole alright done, sorry

Comment: And again, these don't look real. Your second trigger is inserting into `energy_product_id` in `value`, but that column isn't in your table definition. (If it's meant to be `product_id`, then you're trying to insert 'MWh' into a number...) The "verifiable" bit of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your insert statement more closely, and reformat it to make it clearer which values match to which columns:

```
INSERT INTO VALUE
(value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd,
  value_tx, utc_offset, data_Date, hr_utc,
  hr, hr_num, data_code, create_Dt,
  create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt,
  inactive_dt)
values('3', 'Mwh', null, null,
  :NEW.PostedValue, :NEW.UTCOffset, :NEW.Data_Date, :NEW.Data_Type,
  :NEW.UTCValue, :NEW.Hour, :NEW.data_code, null,
  null, null, null, null,
  null);
```

So you're setting `value_tx` to `:NEW.PostedValue` which I assume is right though the names are string; `utc_offset` to `:NEW.UTCOffset`, `data_Date` to `:NEW.Data_Date`, `hr_utc` to `:NEW.Data_Type` which sounds odd, `hr` to `:NEW.Hour`, `hr_num` to `:NEW.data_code`, `data_code` to null...

Hang on, those last two at least look wrong. Surely you should be setting `data_code` to `:NEW.data_code`?

The value you're inserting for `data_code` is `'SYS'`, and `hr_num` is a number - hence the error you're getting, that string cannot go into a number column.

Some of the other columns look dodgy but might just be inconsistent names. That mapping is definitely wrong though.

And as Matt Gibson pointed out, trying to put the string `'Mwh'` into the numeric `Product_Id` (or `energy_product_id`!) column will get the same error.

You need to be careful about (a) inserting the right values into the right columns; and (b) using the right data types. Some of your column data type choices look strange anyway, like `data_date` which sounds like it should be a `DATE` but you have as a `Varchar2(7)` - even for storing a date as a string (a bad idea!) that's strange; it isn't obvious what actual date a value like `'1082019'` might represent.

Comment: *Obviously* '1082019' is the 108th day of 2019. Unless it's in US date format, where it would of course be the 10th minute of the 820th day of the Hayes presidency.

Comment: Ah, I’d assumed it was the 19th day of 1082 and the OP is digitising data from the Domesday Book census. Silly me.